# Xcode incompatible pointer types subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, warnings

I'm getting this warning in Xcode when I try to send an object which is a subclass of the expected class.

`[reminder addContactsObject:individual];` addContactsObject method is expecting that the input should be of type `Contact`. The `individual` that I'm sending is a subclass of `Contact` (`Individual : Contact`).

So why is this generating a warning?

Edit: Added code...

**Reminder.h**

```
@interface Reminder : NSManagedObject

- (void)addContactsObject:(Contact *)value;
```

**Contact.h**

```
@interface Contact : NSManagedObject
```

**Individual.h**

```
@interface Individual : Contact
```

Comment: What is the declaration for individual? I guess there is not a Individual declaration. Maybe post some code will help.

Comment: probably need to include the Individual header. If you don't the compiler won't know the superclass

Comment: @PauldeLange right on the money :) I've forgotten the header...Add it as an answer to get your reward :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably need to include the Individual header. If you don't the compiler won't know the superclass

Comment: Nice one. I had a `@class Subclass` in the header so it was compiling just fine, less this error. Had me stumped for a bit.